# JavaScript: cotangent and arccotangent

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry

I had searched on the internet and I could not find the method of the `Math` object that returns the `ctg` and `arcctg` of an angle. Is there such a method or should I just create my own function using these mathematical formulas:

[image]

[image]

Comment: you may have a look into the docs for [`Math`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math) (some methods may not be working on IE)

Comment: You should create your own functions.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is not, and if you want them you will have to define them yourself. Fortunately, they are easy:

```
function ctg(x) { return 1 / Math.tan(x); }
function arcctg(x) { return Math.PI / 2 - Math.atan(x); }
```